# .NET Dropdown not being retrieved properly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code which populates the drop down:

```
    string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LiSQL"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlDataAdapter myda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [PostAbbrev], [State] FROM [States]", con))
        {
            myda.Fill(ds);
            ddlState.DataSource = ds;
        }
    }

    ddlState.DataTextField = "State";
    ddlState.DataValueField = "State";
    ddlState.DataBind();
```

My dropdown code is as such:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" DataTextField="States" DataValueField="States">                                         
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

When I select say Texas the value still defaults to the first entry Alabama:
Here is what I did for to retrieve the value:

```
    string state = ddlState.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Comment: where are you binding this `dropdown`? If you are doing in `PageLoad` make sure you do it in `If(!Page.IsPostback)`

Comment: Agree with @rs. Also note that you seem to have bound to the wrong field 'States' in you markup, whereas you have bound to 'State' in the codebehind, probably worth removing the duplication.